# Confused, keeps on giving me an error for some reason

Tags: python

```
bilal = input("Please enter a number")

if bilal == 1:
    print(multiplcation())
elif bilal==2:
    print(divison())
else:
    print(rasied_to_the_power())

def multiplcation(a=int(input("enter a number :")),b= int(input("enter a number :"))):
    return a*b
print(multiplcation())

def divison(a=int(input("enter a number :")),b= int(input("enter a number :"))):
    return a/b
print(divison())


def rasied_to_the_power(a=int(input("enter a number :")),b= int(input("enter a number :"))):
    return a**b
print(rasied_to_the_power())
```

Above you can see my code. When the output runs when I enter 1, from what I think it should run the multiplcation fucntion and if I were to enter 2 it should run the divison function. But I keep on getting an error is there something wrong i am doing I dont understand. The error i get is

```
Please enter a number 1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 6, in <module>
NameError: name 'divison' is not defined
```

Here is the two links to the output :

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please add error  also

Comment: Please add error with the full traceback

Comment: I added the error!

Comment: Why are you trying to put input() functions as default parameters?

Comment: You need to put the functions above the lines where you call them …

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `bilal = input("Please enter a number")` to `bilal = int(input("Please enter a number"))` because your are checking the values as integer and write the functions above the code becuase python reads it from up to down

Please write the function in a proper way

```
def multiplcation(a=int(input("enter a number :")),b= int(input("enter a number :"))):
    return a*b
```

instead of that write it like that

```
  def multiplcation():
    a=int(input("enter a number :"))
    b= int(input("enter a number :"))
    return a*b
```

and same with the all of three functions

Here is the whole edited code use it instead:

```
def multiplcation():
    a=int(input("enter a number :"))
    b= int(input("enter a number :"))
    return a*b

def divison():
    a=int(input("enter a number :"))
    b= int(input("enter a number :"))
    return a/b

def rasied_to_the_power():
    a=int(input("enter a number :"))
    b= int(input("enter a number :"))
    return a**b

bilal = int(input("Please enter a number"))

if bilal == 1:
    print(multiplcation())
elif bilal==2:
    print(divison())
else:
    print(rasied_to_the_power())
```

Comment: @mirrat You no longer get the error you posted! Works fine. If you expected something else, edit your question to include that

Comment: the error is not solved after doing that it says that the functions arent defined!

Comment: the whole code is at the top in the question, that is the code!

Comment: @mirratrashid i included the whole code in the answer now happy coding;) and if it works mark it as the right answer :))

Comment: @mirratrashid instead of writing 2*2 write the both 2's in different inputs

Comment: WOW, thank you so much! That makes alot of sense.

Comment: @mirratrashid Welcome and please mark it as right answer if you can . Happy coding:)))

Comment: @TechEasy2BeTechnical sure will, let me figure out how to do that i am new to this stuff! I think I did it!

Answer (score 0):

Python is evaluated top to bottom. You need to define functions before their usage

For your second error, you've defined functions that expect inputs `(a, b)`. You've called each of the functions with no inputs

Comment: umm, i tried but it still didn't work i could post the pictures by editing my original question. You can have a look at the output yourself.

Comment: Move all def usages to the top of the file. Put all print lines and `bilal =`underneath

Comment: According to the images, I solved your error. Doesn't mean that your code doesn't have other logic issues that prevent the output you expect

Comment: I am new to python and my code probably has a lot of logical issues but i still couldn't like get the code to run how i wanted to even after moving the def to the top of the file!

Comment: The code in your first image is correct, you only need to change `if int(bilal) == 1`. For the second error, remove `a,b` in each function parameter list